# How to access name of elements in React useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to setup a component that lists a bunch of titles. Each title has a '+' next to it and when you click on the '+', another component will show that has more information. I know how to do this so that only one component can show at a time, but I wanted to make it so that multiple components could be viewed at once.

This is my code so far

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import MattressUpgrade from "./CamperMods/MattressUpgrade";

const CamperModsContainer = () => {
  const [iconType, setIconType] = useState({
    mattressUpgrade: "",
  });

  const [show, setShow] = useState({
    mattressUpgrade: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setIconType({
      mattressUpgrade: "fas fa-plus-square",
    });
    setShow({
      mattressUpgrade: false,
    });
  }, []);

  let onClickHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let payload = event.currentTarget;
    toggleShow(payload);
  };

  const toggleShow = (payload) => {
    debugger;
    if (payload.value === true) {
      setIconType.payload.id("fas fa-minus-square");
      setShow.payload.id(true);
    } else if (payload.value === false) {
      setIconType.payload.id("fas fa-plus-square");
      setShow.payload.id(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Camper Modifications</h1>
      <p>
        As much as we love the Wolf Pup (aka the &apos;Gray Ghost&apos;), there
        are some things that we tweaked...
      </p>
      <div className="flex-row">
        <h3>Mattress Upgrade</h3>
        <button
          type="button"
          id={show.mattressUpgrade.key}
          value={show.mattressUpgrade}
          className={iconType.mattressUpgrade}
          onClick={onClickHandler}
        ></button>
      </div>
      {show === true && <MattressUpgrade />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CamperModsContainer;
```

The problem is that setting the id to `id={show.mattressUpgrade.key}` doesn't work. When I hit the debugger in the `toggleShow` I can access `payload.value` and get a value of `false`. But if I try to do `payload.id` it gives back an empty string and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why does the button need an `id` anyway? Also what are you expecting `show.mattressUpgrade.key` to be? I can tell you the things wrong here, but I don't really understand what your goal is with the problem code.

Comment: And why are you setting state like this `setIconType.payload.id`? `useState` returns a function, you just need to call it

Comment: Currently there is just one element in each of those useStates, `mattresssUpgrade`. But there will be more. So I was trying to figure out how I can upgrade only that specific element of the useState. For example if the '+' is clicked next to Mattress Upgrade I would want to update the state of `useMattress` only, not every element that might be in the `show` useState.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for computed properties, but there are several other misunderstandings here that are worth highlighting.

A general suggestion is to try to keep datatypes consistent when possible. Converting between a string an boolean is hard to follow and debug. If you end up switching between more complex datatypes (objects, etc) it becomes very error prone.

The first problem is that `show.mattressUpgrade.key` does not work, and it will never work. `key` is accessed as an object property on `show.mattressUpgrade`, but `show.mattressUpgrade` is not an object, its `false`. You can expand and run the below snippet to see that accessing a property on `false` yields `undefined`, and assigning `undefined` as the input's `id` results in `e.target.id` of an empty string.

```js
const Example = () => {
  const test = false;
  console.log('test.property', test.property);
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.id)
  }
  
  return <input id={test.property} onChange={handleChange} />
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I can't tell you how you should set the `id` for the `button`'s in your code because there is only one in your example, but this is why id does not work.

As for the updating state dynamically, `setShow.payload.id` this is not the right way to go. `setShow` is a function, not an object. Even if it were, you would not be referencing it by the variable `payload.id`, you would be attempting to access a **literal** nested property called "payload" then "id". Even further, `id` is not expected to be a function, but you still call it as one.

To access object properties dynamically, you use array syntax (`ojb['property']`). Your function would then be something like this:

```js
  const toggleShow = (payload) => {
    debugger;
    if (payload.value === true) {
      setIconType(prev => ({...prev, [payload.id]: "fas fa-minus-square"}));
      setShow(prev => ({...prev, [payload.id]: true}));
    } else if (payload.value === false) {
      setIconType(prev => ({...prev, [payload.id]: "fas fa-plus-square"}));
      setShow(prev => ({...prev, [payload.id]: false}));
    }
  };
```

Notice we also use a functional update and spread `prev` into the new object in order to keep any values that are not explicitly replaced.

Comment: So I guess my follow-up question would be, what should I research to figure out how to do an accordion style layout using React hooks, that allows more than one section to be displayed at a time? I'm new to coding (obviously) and struggling to find examples of how to accomplish this with hooks vs class syntax.

Comment: What about it is different than in a class component? The issues here aren't really specific to functional components, they're general JavaScript misunderstandings that would also cause issues in a class. Unfortunately I don't have any recommendations and where to find examples of this functionality.